# Optimizing gaussian heatmap generation

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision

I have a set of 68 keypoints (size [68, 2]) that I am mapping to gaussian heatmaps. To do this, I have the following function:

```
def generate_gaussian(t, x, y, sigma=10):

    """
    Generates a 2D Gaussian point at location x,y in tensor t.
    x should be in range (-1, 1).
    sigma is the standard deviation of the generated 2D Gaussian.
    """
    h,w = t.shape

    # Heatmap pixel per output pixel
    mu_x = int(0.5 * (x + 1.) * w)
    mu_y = int(0.5 * (y + 1.) * h)

    tmp_size = sigma * 3

    # Top-left
    x1,y1 = int(mu_x - tmp_size), int(mu_y - tmp_size)

    # Bottom right
    x2, y2 = int(mu_x + tmp_size + 1), int(mu_y + tmp_size + 1)
    if x1 >= w or y1 >= h or x2 < 0 or y2 < 0:
        return t

    size = 2 * tmp_size + 1
    tx = np.arange(0, size, 1, np.float32)
    ty = tx[:, np.newaxis]
    x0 = y0 = size // 2

    # The gaussian is not normalized, we want the center value to equal 1
    g = torch.tensor(np.exp(- ((tx - x0) ** 2 + (ty - y0) ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2)))

    # Determine the bounds of the source gaussian
    g_x_min, g_x_max = max(0, -x1), min(x2, w) - x1
    g_y_min, g_y_max = max(0, -y1), min(y2, h) - y1

    # Image range
    img_x_min, img_x_max = max(0, x1), min(x2, w)
    img_y_min, img_y_max = max(0, y1), min(y2, h)

    t[img_y_min:img_y_max, img_x_min:img_x_max] = \
      g[g_y_min:g_y_max, g_x_min:g_x_max]

    return t

def rescale(a, img_size):
    # scale tensor to [-1, 1]
    return 2 * a / img_size[0] - 1
```

My current code uses a for loop to compute the gaussian heatmap for each of the 68 keypoint coordinates, then stacks the resulting tensors to create a [68, H, W] tensor:

```
x_k1 = [generate_gaussian(torch.zeros(H, W), x, y) for x, y in rescale(kp1.numpy(), frame.shape)]
x_k1 = torch.stack(x_k1, dim=0)
```

However, this method is super slow. Is there some way that I can do this without a for loop?

Edit:

I tried @Cris Luengo's proposal to compute a 1D Gaussian:

```
def generate_gaussian1D(t, x, y, sigma=10):
    h,w = t.shape

    # Heatmap pixel per output pixel
    mu_x = int(0.5 * (x + 1.) * w)
    mu_y = int(0.5 * (y + 1.) * h)

    tmp_size = sigma * 3

    # Top-left
    x1, y1 = int(mu_x - tmp_size), int(mu_y - tmp_size)

    # Bottom right
    x2, y2 = int(mu_x + tmp_size + 1), int(mu_y + tmp_size + 1)
    if x1 >= w or y1 >= h or x2 < 0 or y2 < 0:
        return t

    size = 2 * tmp_size + 1
    tx = np.arange(0, size, 1, np.float32)
    ty = tx[:, np.newaxis]
    x0 = y0 = size // 2

    g = torch.tensor(np.exp(-np.power(tx - mu_x, 2.) / (2 * np.power(sigma, 2.))))
    g = g * g[:, None]

    g_x_min, g_x_max = max(0, -x1), min(x2, w) - x1
    g_y_min, g_y_max = max(0, -y1), min(y2, h) - y1

    img_x_min, img_x_max = max(0, x1), min(x2, w)
    img_y_min, img_y_max = max(0, y1), min(y2, h)

    t[img_y_min:img_y_max, img_x_min:img_x_max] = \
      g[g_y_min:g_y_max, g_x_min:g_x_max]

    return t
```

but my output ends up being an incomplete gaussian.

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One obvious way to speed this up is to compute a 1D Gaussian and multiply it with itself transposed. You compute the Gaussian expression for all points in an NxN grid, most of those are redundant computations, you really only need (N-1)/2 of those, then NxN multiplications.

Comment: Also, since all your sigmas are identical, compute the `g` array only once.

Comment: Do you mean that I should use ```g = np.exp(-np.power(x - mu, 2.) / (2 * np.power(sig, 2.)))``` to generate the gaussian? Is there any way that you can provide a concrete example?

Comment: Yes. And then you do `g = g * g[:,None]` to make a 2D Gaussian. But you should definitely not recompute that same Gaussian for every key point, generate it once and store it for repeated use.

Comment: Note also that you can use the Gaussian's symmetry: only compute for `x-mu` from 1 to `tmp_size`, flip over to fill out the left half, and write 1 for the element at `x=mu`. `np.exp()` is an expensive call, the fewer you do, the faster your program will be.

Comment: I modified the code, but I ended up getting an incomplete gaussian. I updated the post accordingly for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generate an NxN array `g` with a Gaussian centered on its center pixel. N is computed such that it extends by `3*sigma` from that center pixel. This is the fastest way to build such an array:

```py
tmp_size = sigma * 3
tx = np.arange(1, tmp_size + 1, 1, np.float32)
g = np.exp(-(tx**2) / (2 * sigma**2))
g = np.concatenate((np.flip(g), [1], g))
g = g * g[:, None]
```

What we're doing here is compute half a 1D Gaussian. We don't even bother computing the value of the Gaussian for the middle pixel, which we know will be 1. We then build the full 1D Gaussian by flipping our half-Gaussian and concatenating. Finally, the 2D Gaussian is built by the outer product of the 1D Gaussian with itself.

We could shave a bit of extra time by building a quarter of the 2D Gaussian, then concatenating four rotated copies of it. But the difference in computational cost is not very large, and this is much simpler. Note that `np.exp` is the most expensive operation here by far, so just minimizing how often we call it we significantly reduce the computational cost.

---

However, the best way to speed up the complete code is to compute the array `g` only once, rather than anew for each key point. Note how your sigma doesn't change, so all the arrays `g` that are computed are identical. If you compute it only once, it no longer matters which method you use to compute it, since this will be a minimal portion of the total program anyway.

You could, for example, have a global variable `_gaussian` to hold your array, and have your function compute it only the first time it is called. Or you could separate your function into two functions, one that constructs this array, and one that copies it into an image, and call them as follows:

```py
g = create_gaussian(sigma=3)
x_k1 = [
    copy_gaussian(torch.zeros(H, W), x, y, g)
    for x, y in rescale(kp1.numpy(), frame.shape)
]
```

---

On the other hand, you're likely best off using existing functionality. For example, DIPlib has a function [dip.DrawBandlimitedPoint()](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/generation_drawing.html#dip-DrawBandlimitedPoint-dip-Image-L-dip-FloatArray--Image-Pixel-CL-dip-FloatArray--dip-dfloat-) [disclosure: I'm an author] that adds a Gaussian blob to an image. Likely you'll find similar functions in other libraries.